# Can not open file that I know is there using PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have looked all over the Internet and all over Stack Overflow and I am unable to find a solution to my problem.

I basically have a PDF file which I am able to access through a web address if I hit in a web browser.
Without away, it is: http://url.com/manage/pdf/file.pdf?id=172). I know it seems unusual, but trust me, hitting this address gives my a PDF file.

But if I try an hit it using file_get_contents, I get an error:

*failed to open stream: Connection timed out* (obviously I have cut out file names and line numbers).

I am not looking to to suppress the error (I already can do this), nor am I looking it for a way to handle the error. I want to know WHY the error is happening so I can stop it from happening.

Particularly as this same line of code has no issues with getting other files in a similar manner.

Because of constraints beyond my control, I can not use cURL.

The file is less than 1MB and all the relevant settings in php.ini have been checked (can't remember them off the top of my head, but allow open socket, and socket time outs).

Can anyone give me an answer that I have not seen already that will actually work! Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You should be using `file_get_contents`, not `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Well, the `id=172` part tells me that the file is referenced in a database table. The file is fetched based on this ID (probably something like `SELECT filename FROM file_table WHERE ID=?`, then passed through to the client.

Comment: apologies I, meant to write file_get_contents

Comment: Edit your question, there is a very big difference between `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a file to a remote server.  If you are trying to **open** the PDF from that site you need to use `file_get_contents()`.

http://url.com/manage/pdf/file.pdf?id=172

Your link includes the word 'manage.' If you need to be logged in to see that file then yes your browser would see it but PHP cannot because it isn't logged into the server.  The second issue is if I view that link I am redirected to http://www.coolchaser.com/?id=172.  If you are dealing with a link that may have a redirect you should switch to CURL and in the curl options you tell it to redirect and the number of levels of redirection that are allowed.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url.com/manage/pdf/file.pdf?id=172');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I hear you about the logging in part. Would it not give an access denied error is this was the case? As for the second part, I have replaced the url part of the link from the actual address.

Comment: No.  There is no rule saying that you must return an access denied and it is fairly common practice these days to direct someone to another page if they link to something that needs a login.

If you used something like what I added to my comment it would follow the redirect and return something.

Comment: Turns out that the fact that you had to be logged in was the problem in this case! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can't `file_put_contents` to a web address like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying open a file from a web address! This cannot be done with `file_put_contents()`.

See **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)** for the reference.

***If you are trying to add data to a file then the file must be in a writable directory on your local server.***